# Get links in list using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to make my each "li"(st) tag redirect to a page when clicked. I am not sure what the best way to do this is, but I have the following HTML navigation setup:

```
          <nav class="navigation_menu" id="navigation_menu">
              <div class="menu-icon"></div>
              <ul>
                <li><span id = 'title' class = 'left title'>Cricket</span></li>
                <li><a href = "index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href = "services.php">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href = "prices.php">Prices</a></li>
                <li><a href = "contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href = "suport.php">Support</a></li>
                <li class = 'button'><button id = 'getstarted'>GET STARTED</button></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
```

I'm fairly new to jQuery so I am not 100% confident on how to do this.

Comment: So you want to redirect to the pages defined in href but using jQuery? Is that correct?

Comment: @mcv - yes, sorry for not clarifying. I have anchor tags with href='' links and I would like my list tags to also redirect. It only redirect when you click on 'home' for example not the list.

Comment: Little odd request...because, basically, you have a tags set inside list items. What is your css? give display:block; to a tags, to occupy whole width of list items...

Comment: Why not remove the bullets that come with the li tag in css?

Comment: ul{list-style-type: none;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Javascript for stuff you can do trivially in CSS:

```css
li {
  background: red;
}
a {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation_menu" id="navigation_menu">
              <div class="menu-icon"></div>
              <ul>
                <li><span id = 'title' class = 'left title'>Cricket</span></li>
                <li><a href = "index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href = "services.php">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href = "prices.php">Prices</a></li>
                <li><a href = "contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href = "suport.php">Support</a></li>
                <li class = 'button'><button id = 'getstarted'>GET STARTED</button></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
```

The `background` rules are only used to illustrate that the `a` element is now exactly the same size as the parent `li` - you can ignore them for your code.